# Find values of $a$ such that $\frac{x^2-x}{1-ax}$ attains all real values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Find values of $a$ such that
>   $$\frac{x^2-x}{1-ax}$$
>   attains all real values.

I first tried to find the range of the above by equating the above to some $y$. Solving I get $x^2+x(ay-1)-y=0$. How do I proceed?

Comment: Not clear what you mean: The function $f(a,x)=\frac{x^2-x}{1-ax}$ will simplify to $f(1,x)=-x$ which attains all real values.

Comment: @gammatester Which means that $1$ is one value of $a$ for which the expression attains all real values, and OP needs to find all such values of $a$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $f(x)=\frac{x^2-x}{1-ax}=k$ for some fixed constants $a,k$. Solving for $x$ we get
$$x^2-x=k(1-ax)=k-kax$$
$$x^2+(ka-1)x-k=0$$
$$x=\frac{1-ka\pm\sqrt{(ka-1)^2+4k}}2$$
For a chosen $a$, $f$ attains all real numbers if and only if the discriminant $(ka-1)^2+4k$ is non-negative for all $k$. Expanding:
$$(ak)^2-2ka+1+4k\ge0$$
$$a^2k^2+(4-2a)k+1\ge0$$
Using the discriminant a second time we find
$$(4-2a)^2-4(a^2)(1)\le0$$
$$16-16a+4a^2-4a^2\le0$$
$$16\le16a$$
$$a\ge1$$
If $a=1$, $f(x)$ behaves like $-x$. However, it has a removable singularity at $x=1$, which means it does not *attain* a value of $-1$. Therefore $a=1$ is excluded, and $\frac{x^2-x}{1-ax}$ attains all real values when $a>1$.

Comment: f attains real numbers for any real x as long as the denominator is not zero.

Comment: @AmeetSharma No, did you read the question? _All_ real values, not just one. Please retract your downvote.

Comment: oops sorry about that.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel But my textbook also includes $a=1$.

Comment: @J.Deff In an informal setting where you could simplify the expression at $a=1$ to $-x$, $a=1$ would be included, but that relies on the cancellation of an $x-1$ term and as a mathematician you have to pay attention to whether or not you can do that. Perhaps your textbook's inclusion of $a=1$ is a simple oversight.

Comment: How did you get the idea that we have to check the function at a =1?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Let's say $a$ takes the value $2$, but then the function would be $\mathrm{f(x)=\frac{x^2-x}{1-2x}}$ which wont be defined for $\mathrm{x=1/2}$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel How did you conclude that the discriminant (second) is $\leq 0$ ?...

Comment: Hi, this might be a bit late but I have one doubt. How are we sure that 1 is the only value which we will have to ignore?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Calculate the discriminant and see when this stays non-negative for every value of $y$.

Comment: $a^2y^2+2y(2-a)+1 \geq 0$

Comment: Then continue and calculate yet a discriminant to see when this is verified. Note that this time the discriminant should be non-positive! (the case $a=1$ needs special attention).

Comment: Didn't understand